# sharepoint document files on Ipad

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, offline-sync

our company have several safety documents on a SharePoint document library. we have several people working on the field. there are 30 ipads shared between these people . each Ipad needs to have local copy and the most updated safety documents from share-point on it. these Ipads dont have internet most of the time. but we need the local copy to be autosync when ever these laptops have internet connection.

is there anyway to automate the process downloading syncing and keeping local copy on ipads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if using OneDrive App for iOS is feasible for your requirement.

Mark files or folders "offline" to read them anytime, even when you aren't connected to the Internet. Online edits made to the files sync the next time your iPad, iPhone or iPod Touch connects to the Web, so you get the latest version of the file.

More information check the TechNet article:

[Read files or folders offline in OneDrive for iOS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/read-files-or-folders-offline-in-onedrive-for-ios-60ffb5d6-ac87-4bea-b142-01f301b22e4c)